# adding images in JFrame, image when clicked

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, actionlistener

I want to make a "simple" program. it consists of three buttons and when you click on one of them i want a picture to show up, but i don't know how to add the image properly. 
If anyone has played pokemon i want to make the start where you select your starter pokemon.

Here is my code.

```
public LayoutLek(){

    super("Starter");
    panel=new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
    top_p=new JPanel();                             

    label1=new JLabel("Make a choice");
    label1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30));
    label1.setForeground(Color.black);

    ImageIcon green = new ImageIcon("Bilder/bulbasaur.jpg");   //Dont know if it is correct but...
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel(green);

    top_p.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    top_p.add(label1);
    bottom_p=new JPanel();                          
    bottom_p.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));

    panel.add(top_p);
    panel.add(bottom_p);

    button1=new JButton("Button 1");
    button1.setBackground(Color.green);
    button1.setForeground(Color.black);
    button1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24));
    button2=new JButton("Button 2");
    button2.setBackground(Color.red);
    button2.setForeground(Color.black);
    button2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24));
    button3=new JButton("Button 3");
    button3.setBackground(Color.blue);
    button3.setForeground(Color.black);
    button3.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24));

    bottom_p.add(button1);
    bottom_p.add(button2);
    bottom_p.add(button3);

    button1.addActionListener(this);
    button2.addActionListener(this);
    button3.addActionListener(this);

    this.add(panel);
    //this.setSize(350, 300);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new LayoutLek();

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Clicked");      //Just to test
    Object src = e.getSource();
    if(src==button1){
                       //Here should the image show up
    }
    else if(src==button2){

    }
    else if(src==button3){

    }

}
```

If anyone can help i would be thankful!

Answer (score 2):

1. Images that are embedded into your program should be loaded from the class path, not the file system. When you pass a String to the `ImageIcon` your telling the program to look in the file system. To load from the class path, use

   ```
   new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Bilder/bulbasaur.jpg");
   ```

   where `Bilder` need to be in the `src`
2. Your `JLabel label2` is locally scoped within the constructor, so you can't access it from outside the constructor, i.e. the `actionPerformed`. You need to declare it outside the constructor, as class members, as you seem to have done with your other objects.
3. Have all *three* `ImageIcons` already initialized As class members also.
4. Just use `label2.setIcon(oneOfTheImageIcons);` in the `actionPerformed` to change the icon of the `JLabel`
5. Swing apps should be run from the Event Dispatch Thread. You can do so by wrapping your `new LayoutLek();` in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater..`. See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for complete details.
6. You never add your `label2` to a visible conainter.

After fixing all the above mentioned points, here is a runnable refactor. You just need to change your file paths accordingly.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class LayoutLek extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JPanel panel;
    JPanel top_p;
    JLabel label1;
    JPanel bottom_p;
    JButton button1;
    JButton button2;
    JButton button3;

    ImageIcon green;
    ImageIcon blue;
    ImageIcon red;
    JLabel label2;

    public LayoutLek() {
        super("Starter");

        green = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/path/to/imgage"));
        blue = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/path/to/imgage"));
        red = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/path/to/imgage"));
        label2 = new JLabel(green);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        top_p = new JPanel();

        label1 = new JLabel("Make a choice");
        label1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30));
        label1.setForeground(Color.black);

        top_p.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        top_p.add(label1);
        bottom_p = new JPanel();
        bottom_p.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));

        panel.add(top_p);
        panel.add(bottom_p);

        button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        button1.setBackground(Color.green);
        button1.setForeground(Color.black);
        button1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24));
        button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        button2.setBackground(Color.red);
        button2.setForeground(Color.black);
        button2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24));
        button3 = new JButton("Button 3");
        button3.setBackground(Color.blue);
        button3.setForeground(Color.black);
        button3.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24));

        bottom_p.add(button1);
        bottom_p.add(button2);
        bottom_p.add(button3);

        button1.addActionListener(this);
        button2.addActionListener(this);
        button3.addActionListener(this);

        this.add(panel);
        this.add(label2, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        //this.setSize(350, 300);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new LayoutLek();
            }
        });
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Clicked");      //Just to test
        Object src = e.getSource();
        if (src == button1) {
            label2.setIcon(green);
        } else if (src == button2) {
            label2.setIcon(blue);
        } else if (src == button3) {
            label2.setIcon(red);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! the label2 wasn't actually nessecary. i added the image to label1 which i should have guessed...
thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `src.equals(button1)`. It's better practise to use the object-based equals method, == is better applied to primitive comparison (i.e. `int`, `long`, `boolean`, etc).

Secondly, you can do a couple of things.

1. Add the image to a container, then remove it and add another each time a button is clicked.
2. Add all three images to a container, set them all to invisible (`setVisible(false)`) and then in `src.equals(button1/2/3)` you set the appropriate image to visible. Container may need to be repainted.

Hope this helps!